# How to indicate dependent entity in one to one relationship using shadow foreign keys only?

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-fluent-api

I have specified:

```
public class Cart
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
}
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public virtual Cart Cart { get; set; }
}
...
modelBuilder.Entity<Cart>(e =>
{
    e.HasOne(e => e.ApplicationUser).WithOne(re => re.Cart);
    e.Property(e => e.ApplicationUser).IsRequired();
});
```

my intention was that Cart cannot exist without ApplicationUser associated with it, but `ApplicationUser` can.

Unfortunately when I generate migration I get error:

> 'ApplicationUser' cannot be used as a property on entity type 'Cart'
> because it is configured as a navigation.

So it seems that I can't express that `ApplicationUser` is indeed required because the `Cart` is dependent entity. How to fix that not having to declare explicit foreign keys, just using shadow ones?

Answer (score 0):

The shadow property can be specified by using a string argument in `HasForeignKey`:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().HasOne(e => e.Cart)
    .WithOne(e => e.ApplicationUser)
    .HasForeignKey<Cart>("ApplicationUserId");
```

The foreign key field in the database has a `NOT NULL` specification.